# Make a Java applet take 100% height of the parent element

Tags: java, html, css, applet

I have this popup window that divides the screen to two rows, one fluid (blue)  and the other have constant height of 64px (Green).

if the applet is set to 100% height - it will ignore its container and swollen 100 height of the popup

```
<applet id="jumpLoaderApplet" width="100%" height="90%"></applet>
```

If the height is 90% - there will be a visible 10% (See blue part in the pic)

Blue row contains a java applet - I am having issues making the java applet take 100% height of its parent div.
When there is no applet - there is no problem.

```
.content {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:64px;
    background:blue;
}
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
    bottom:0;
    background:green;
}
```

[Here is the code along with the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/7vL7o0v9/)

See the blue part- its part of the applet div:
[image: See the blue part- its part of the applet div]

Comment: What is the container of this div? Does it have `position: relative;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the height of the parent element to `100%` minus the `64px` at the bottom:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

In doing so, you can now give the `applet` a height of `100%` of the parent.

```
.applet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

.. you could also just use `calc()` to set the height of the `applet` too:

```
.applet {
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
}
```

.. or you could absolutely position the `applet` within the parent element:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
    top: 0;
}
.applet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

---

It's worth pointing out that you can also use viewport percentage values:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

You can therefore use `100vh` rather than `100%`: `calc(100vh - 64px)`:

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

.. likewise:

```
.applet {
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}
```

---

If you're interested in browser support for `calc()`, [see here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Also, support for viewport lengths can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).